# Proving that $g=f^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

For $f: A \rightarrow B$, $g: B \rightarrow C$ and $A=B=C$, I want to show that $f \circ g=g \circ f=id_A \rightarrow g=f^{-1}$.

My attempt:

If $g= f^{-1}$ then $f \circ g=f \circ f^{-1}=id_B=id_A$ and $g \circ f=f^{-1} \circ f=id_A$, so $f \circ g=g \circ f$. Thus, $f \circ g=g \circ f=id_A \rightarrow g=f^{-1}$.

I'm not so confident in my attempt because I started of by assuming $g=f^{-1}$ and I'm wondering if my proof is incorrect or it needs better structuring.

Comment: As you said, you shouldn't start by assuming $f^{-1}=g$ as it is what you need to prove. Start by writing down $f^{-1}$ or $g$ and see where you can get by using what you know. For esample, $g=g\circ id_A=g\circ f\circ f^{-1}$ and then try to go further

Answer (score 2):

$$f^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ id_A=f^{-1}\circ (f\circ g)=(f^{-1}\circ f)\circ g=id_A\circ g=g.$$